# Calculate totals based on another cell

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

Let's say you have a table like this

| Frequency | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| Monthly | 10.99 |
| Annually | 11.99 |
| Monthly | 12.99 |
| Annually | 13.99 |
| Monthly | 10.99 |

What's the best formula to calculate the total of items that have a monthly cost and then the total of items that have an Annually cost?

So replace X's with the totals

| Monthly Total | Annually Total |
| --- | --- |
| X | X |

Note the table above is simplified and I have over 200 rows

Comment: Look into SUMIFS.

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMIF(A2:A99,"Monthly",B2:B99)
```

This seems to work